# html tags does not work inside jsx made tags

Tags: reactjs, keystonejs

I've been using the package `express-react-views` on a keystone.js project, and so I'm generating my views statically. However, the native HTML tags seem to not work when put inside a custom component I made.

Let's say the I have the following:

```
office.name = name
office.address = lorem ipsum
office.contactInfo.phone = 123
office.contactInfo.fax = 456
```

and if I render the following:

```
<Stub textPosition="right" title={"Office / " + office.name}>
    {office.address}
    <small>Tel: {office.contactInfo.phone}</small>
    <br />
    <small>Fax: {office.contactInfo.fax}</small>
</Stub>
```

It renders somewhat like this:

```
NAME
lorem.ipsum
,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

It seems to me that the three tags became objects.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I am curious what is inside if your office.contactInfo.fax. looks like it is array of objects. Try to print it into console with `console.log` and check what is inside there.

Comment: it's an object actually. an object that contains some other fields.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comment your `{office.contactInfo.fax}` is object but now a single text field. I am not sure what other fields/properties are in there, but to display something in html, you should extract text field from that Fax object.
For example:

```
> fax = {'fax_home': '12345', 'fax_work': '6789'}
> Object {fax_home: "12345", fax_work: "6789"}
> typeof(fax)
> "object"
> fax['fax_home']
> "12345"
```

Also you can iterate over keys in your object to extract what do you need. (this is also possible in react). Just JS:

```
fax = {'fax_home': '12345', 'fax_work': '6789'}
Object.keys(fax).forEach(function (key) {
   console.log(fax[key]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I find out that, for example, if I remove the html tags, the fields such as ```office.contactInfo.fax``` will display properly. They only render wrongly when they are inside the <small> html tag. They render text, but they do still have commas in between.

Comment: in fact, anything I put inside an HTML tag becomes an [object Object], even just static text. so far, only divs work.

Comment: here is the render part of the stub component. I used react-bootstrap as for the <Col> components.
`render: function() {
  
   return (
    <div>
     <Col sm={6} md={6}>
      <h3 className="h3">{this.props.title}</h3>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.children}} />
     </Col>
     <Col sm={6} md={6}>
      
      <img src={this.props.img} className="maxwidth" />
     </Col>
    </div>
   );`